# Remove White background covering 4 columns of products

Tags: html, css

we can see white background covering 4 columns[products] as below

[image]

i want to remove white background & make like this

[image]

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1224px)
.category-products {
    clear: both;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px)
.products-grid {
    background: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1224px)
.catalogsearch-result-index .products-grid > li:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: none;
}
```

Comment: r u create any jsfiddle?

Comment: @falguni i will try to create it now.

Comment: The two links you refer to don't work. Could you update it or provide images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `background-color` and `box-shadow` from `col-main` will solve your problem

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the `styles.css` file in line 11151:

```
.catalogsearch-result-index .col-main {background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #ccc;padding: 10px;}
```

remove/override the `background` and `box-shadow` attributes, and it will work

Answer (score 1):

Use `!important` property. try this code.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1224px){
.catalogsearch-result-index .col-main {
    background: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;

}
}
```

[more about !important](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

Comment: The use of `!important` is discouraged:  https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/